# How to get more than 1000 actions from a Trello board?

Tags: trello

I want to run a simple script which gets in JSON form all the cards, etc. from Trello which data & URL looks like this: https://trello.com/b/Vqrkz3KO.json. I want to automate the process of exporting a board.

But Trello won't let me do that, so I have to do it from the API, like this:

```js
`/1/boards/${board.id}`, {fields: "all",actions: "all",action_fields: "all",activities_limit: 1000,cards: "all",card_fields: "all",card_attachments: true,labels: "all",lists: "all",list_fields: "all",members: "all",member_fields: "all",checklists: "all",checklist_fields: "all", organization: false
```

It does what I want it to do, but the boards which I want to get the cards from have MORE than 1000 activities. So How do I get all the activities? It only fetches 1000 activities/cards. Also, I cant just fetch the URL above because for some reason you cant use the api to fetch it as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390311/is-there-a-way-to-export-an-entire-trello-board-as-json-via-api). This question doesn't answer my question, I want to go past 1000 cards, but if you do, you get an error saying you can't.

Comment: Find all the names for either `fields` or `actions` or etc and make multiple requests for each value

Comment: Just some ideas, I am not a professional. If the export is limited to 1000, contact the Trello support and / or community. It might also be a license issue, perhaps you need to upgrade. Workarounds could be to scrape the Trello site, or copy the project and try deleting those actions that are in the 1000 exported, then export again, asf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**: Finally got it, I used the API & a ID generator for `HTTPS` requests and used the provided `&before=` parameter. The `&before=` parameter uses dates as the arguments, so I had to grab the last action from one request, get the date from that, and provide it for the &before parameter. Then for every array element that had 1000 elements, I popped the last element because I'd end up with duplicate actions.

Now, I ended up with actions that look like this: `[[actions],[actions],[actions],[actions]]` and so on, so I used [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) 's answer to make it all `[actions]`. Then I used bracket notation `object["key"] = value` to set / replace the actions with the actions from my `HTTPS` requests, and it came out to a VERY large file, and it took quite a while to produce this file, it came out to around `99.5 MB`.

this is my whole index.js test file:

```js
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
var boardinfo = "";
https.get({
    hostname: 'trello.com',
    path: `/b/....json`,
    headers: {'User-Agent': `${Math.random().toString(16).substring(2,16)}`}
}, (r) => {
    var data = "";
    r.on('data', (d) => {
        data+=d;
    })
    r.on('close', () => {
        boardinfo = JSON.parse(data);
    });
})

var actions = [];

(function untilDeath(beforeval) {
https.get({
    hostname: 'api.trello.com',
    path: `/1/boards/.../actions?limit=1000${beforeval ? `&before=${beforeval}` : ``}`,
    headers: {'User-Agent': `${Math.random().toString(16).substring(2,16)}`}
}, (r) => {
    var cmpdta = "";
    r.on('data', (d) => {
        cmpdta+=d;
    })
    r.on('close', () => {
        cmpdta = JSON.parse(cmpdta);
        if(cmpdta.length < 1000) {
            if(cmpdta.length) actions.push(cmpdta);
            return makeFile(info, [].concat.apply([], actions), fileName);
        } else
        untilDeath(cmpdta[999].date);
        cmpdta.pop();
        actions.push(cmpdta);
    });

    r.on('error', () => {
        throw new Error('Error');
    });
});
})();

function makeFile(trelloBoard, actions) {
    trelloBoard["actions"] = actions;
    fs.createWriteStream('./full-board.json');
    fs.writeFile(`./full-board.json`, JSON.stringify(trelloBoard, null, `\t`), (c) => {
        if(c) console.log(c);
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: Disappointingly, this also only fetches 1000 actions, even with saving the JSON file manually, it still gives 1000 actions.

I easily resolved this with a HTTPS `User-Agent` header.

```js
const https = require('https');
https.get({
    hostname: 'trello.com',
    path: '/b/....json',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'some-random-user-agent'}
}, (r) => {
    var str = "";
    r.on('data', (d) => {str+=d});
    r.on('close', () => {console.log(str)})
})
```